# Using google provider in next-auth inside postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, next-auth

I am trying to send queries inside postman.
I am using google provider in next-auth.
In the authorization tab
I selected Oauth2.0 and filled with the necessary details and was was issued a access token.
[image]

When sending any `GET` request It always fails with `401` status code.

```
  import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
  export default async function userHandler(req,res){
  const session = await getSession({ req }) 
  console.log(session); // null 
  if (!session) return res.status(401).end();
   ....
```

However this is works fine outside postman perfectly(in the webapp)

Comment: The provided information might not be enough, please let me if any additional information is required.

Comment: You need the app to be allowed to get a token. The following guide is very good. At least for the Google part ;) https://www.postman.com/speeding-resonance-133102/workspace/google-cloud-api/documentation/12689164-9400e5f3-afac-4759-afe4-630a3842b2eb